# Parent not executing in an infinite loop

Tags: c

My goal from the code is the following:
-Generate a random number between a given range
-Make user guess the number using the child process.
-Make the parent tell the user if guess should be higher/lower.
-If guess is correct give a signal for the child to exit.

Current complete code:

```
int main() {

pid_t pid=fork();
int guess;

int* shared_values=mmap(NULL, 3*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);


shared_values[0]= 1+ rand() % 51;
shared_values[2]=0;

if(pid<0){
    printf("Fork failed");
}

if(pid==0){
printf("Enter your guess: \n");
}

while(1)
{

if(pid==0){
    if(shared_values[2]==1)
        exit(0);

scanf("%d", &guess);
shared_values[1]=guess;

}

if(pid>0){

wait(NULL);
    if(shared_values[1]>shared_values[0]){
        printf("Guess should be lower");
    }

    if(shared_values[1]<shared_values[0]){
        printf("Guess should be higher");
    }

    if(shared_values[1]==shared_values[0]){
        printf("WIN");
        shared_values[2]=1;
        break;
    }

}
}
munmap(shared_values, 3*sizeof(int));
return 1;
}
```

I tried to put a `printf` before `if(pid>0)` and it printed once, tried to put it before `wait(NULL)` and it didn't execute so the parent is definitely not executing but why is that?

Comment: You forgot to put newlines at the ends of the strings you're printing, so they're probably being buffered.  That means the `printf` calls probably *were* made, but you didn't see it because it was buffered.  Do this:  Add newlines to the end of *all* your print strings, then run it again.  I would expect your results to be different.

Comment: ... or use `puts` instead of `printf` for printing a string to the standard output.  It will supply the newline automatically, and it is a bit more efficient, too (not that the efficiency will make a noticeable difference to this particular program).

Comment: same result, tried both `printf` with `\n` and `puts` both resulted in the same output as the original code.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  The primary reason is it is missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files.  Please correct this deficiency.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) Please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding: `pid_t pid=fork();
 int guess;

 int* shared_values=mmap(NULL, 3*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);` Since this code is executed, regardless of the returned value from `fork()`  It is executed when `fork()` fails, when in the parent process, when in the child process.  I.e. twice two many times.  Strongly suggest perform the `mmap()` BEFORE calling `fork()` so it is only executed once.

Comment: regarding: `printf("Fork failed");` Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest calling `perror()` as that function will perform both operations

Comment: regarding: `if(pid<0)
 {
  printf("Fork failed");
 }`   The code must NOT execute further if the call to `fork()` failed, so, immediately after the call to `printf()` must be a statement similar to: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. has not been tested for 'race' conditions, I leave that up to the OP
4. properly checks for I/O errors
5. child properly notifies parent if a error occurs via -1 value
6. only produces one shared memory segment
7. properly handles all returned values from `fork()
8. incorporates appropriate horizontal spacing for readability
9. properly initializes the random number generator before calling `rand()`

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main( void ) 
{
    srand( (unsigned)time( void );

    int* shared_values = mmap( NULL, 3*sizeof(int), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 );

    if( (int)shared_values == -1 )
    {
        perror( "mmap failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    shared_values[0] = 1+ rand() % 51;
    shared_values[2] = 0;

    pid_t pid = fork();
    if( pid<0 )
    { // fork() error occurred
        perror( "Fork failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    if( pid==0 )
    { // child process
        int guess;
        while( 1 )
        {
            if( shared_values[2] == 1 )
            {
                exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
            }

            printf("Enter your guess: \n");
            if( scanf( "%d", &guess ) != 1 )
            {
                fprintf( stderr, "scanf for guess failed\n" );
                shared_values[1] = -1;
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            shared_values[1] = guess;
        }  
    }

    // parent process
    while(1)
    {
        if( shared_values[1] == -1 )
        { // child failed
            break;
        }

        else if( shared_values[1] > shared_values[0] )
        {
            printf( "Guess should be lower\n" );
        }

        else if( shared_values[1] < shared_values[0] )
        {
            printf( "Guess should be higher\n" );
        }

        else if( shared_values[1] == shared_values[0] )
        {
            printf( "WIN\n" );
            shared_values[2] = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    wait( NULL );
    munmap( shared_values, 3*sizeof(int) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. No one answered so I did it without shared memory (using pipes), however I took your comments into consideration for the next time I use shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

If understand this correctly, the parent is waiting for the child process to exit before it verifies the answer, through the wait() call. But child process only exits if the answer was marked as correct by the parent process. Therefore the parent blocks on the wait() call and the child gets "feedback" from the parent.